# Inserting data into the db using Parameters with Data Source Controls

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Am trying to insert the variable names into the db using

```
<asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" Defaultvalue = ' <%=names %> ' />
```

But it is inserting `<%=names %>` instead of the actual value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the code how you're trying to insert it?

Comment: UPDATE [Loans] SET [admin]=@name WHERE [Loanid] = @Loanid">

Answer (score 0):

You can't use <%= %> notation with the control; you have to set the parameter from code behind via:

```
Me.DataSourceName.SelectParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = names;
```

Something like that.